# How to find the data related to a specific user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am now learning ASP.NET MVC 5 and working on a little project to improve my knowledge.

Using Entity Framework, I didn't see until now a table for the `Users` although there is a login and register functionality.

I wonder for example: what shall I do when I want show the data related to a specific user? With a code like that:

```
public ActionResult MyAnnoncement()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml");
    }
    else  
    {
        return View(db.Voitures.ToList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use User.Identity.GetUserId() to get the ID of the user from the AspNetUsers table, then populate the User object like this:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
string uid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ApplicationUser u = db.Users.Find(uid);
```

Please note you'll need to add "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;" at the top of your code to use User.Identity.GetUserId().

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I got an error that Identity doesn't contain a Definition for GetUserId()

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, you'll need to include the "using" statement (using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity) at the top of your code.

Comment: I did it sorry I have copied the wrong error. that is now the problem : The view 'MyAnnoncement' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

Comment: @Anouar So create this view, MVC by default search view by controller method name.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of the  UserManager "ApplicationUser can be different in your case can by some other object
Then you can do something like this

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

the user object has your data

Comment: thanks for the answer so to show data related the logged user, I have only to write db.Voitures.ToList() in a condition of the id od the logged user

Comment: Yes you could do it like that when you save the Voiture add a userid propery and then filter by it,  the UserId is of type string